# coreos etcd 3 proxy gateway configuration

Tags: coreos, etcd3

I am trying to setup etcd3 central cluster and nodes with proxy configuration. I am able to do this in etcd2 but how can i configure in etcd3 in coreos using etcd member.service it will be a great help if someone have example configuration.

which one is better way to configure and run etcd3 cluster ?  as service or as container. I am running etcd2 as service. I am trying to upgrade my cluster. from 2.3 to 3.1.5 upgrade process is not clear in coreos.